# Export Lint report from Eclipse IDE

Tags: android, eclipse, performance, lint

I am using lint tool in Eclipse while developing an Android project. I could see the lint warnings in the lint tool console, but i cannot find any option to export this result to either XML or html file.

I know that, report can be generated from command promt, but i need to confirm whether this is possible through Lint tool integrated with Eclipse IDE. If it is possible could any one suggest how to take the report, if not i wonder why eclipse has not provided such a simple feature to the lint tool.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/improving-w-lint.html check this.

Comment: Thanks. I read the above link, but i couldn't find how to generate report (html or xml) from the  result of Lint tool from Eclipse.

Comment: I think there should be down-vote option for comments too... so that new user won't waste hours reading a useless blog on a link. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi As a part of RnD from my end I am closing this thread with the conclusion that we cannot export the lint report when we are running lint from the latest available Eclispe (bundled with ADT) plugin till date. If you are so required to get the report from this plugin, better enhance your own plugin for the same :).

As Kanwalijit answered, if we want to export the Lint report, we need to run the lint from command prompt.

Thanks

Answer (score 14):

1.open command line (cmd in windows)

2.navigate to "tools" directory located in android installation directory

3.here you just have to type :

command -

```
lint --html < html_output_path > < your_android_project_path >
```

eg:

```
lint --html C:\report.html C:\yourAndroidProject\
```

4.go to html_path and open the html test report :)

Comment: Thanks Kanwalijit.. i know we could generate report from command line.. but my question is to generate report from lint tool integrated with Eclipse IDE. :(

Comment: it responding "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: lombok.ast.Node" ..any help here?